# How to avoid antialiasing slits between shapes in NSView?

Tags: cocoa, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I try to build some kind of ”triangular blends” based on the bezier paths. As far i got nice results, there is one problem I have no idea how to solve. 
My shapes are build from hundreds of small triangles, each one is filled with RGBA colour. But between shapes is a visible slit, (probably) caused by antialiasing. With antialiasing off result is much worse.
Does exist a way to ”tune” antialiasing in a NSView?
Or some different approach?

[image: Triangles, triangles! Triangles everywhere!]

Comment: I think this is pretty cool, is there a reason that it was voted down?

Comment: I also don't think this is caused by anti aliasing... maybe some of the places where it looks to disappear is anti aliasing

Comment: Grady, I'm almost sure it's antialiasing. it'z zoom independent. It's transparent. Except this i can see another reason.

Comment: Should be ”..i can't see another reason”

Comment: Hi, what did you use to generate these shapes? they're pretty cool

Comment: My own program i tried to write.

Answer (score 1):

There was only one way!
Separate render alpha and color without antialiasing and combine them at the end.

Before:[image]
and after:[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way is to draw them slightly larger. Outset each path. 
You could also stroke the paths to the same effect. 
Then set the blending mode so they don't mix with each other.

Comment: It's not a way I think. The same size of slit is always, even if I scale everything down or up. This method should know about zoom and add offset depends on. Risky.
Adding outline doesn't help with semi transparent colours. It makes slits darker.

Answer (score 0):

well if you think it is anti-aliasing, then you can turn that off for your graphics context...

```
// about to draw
CGContextRef context = [[NSGraphicsContext currentContext] graphicsPort];
CGContextSetAllowsAntialiasing ( context, false );
// or
CGContextSetShouldAntialias ( context, false );
//draw
```

Comment: I already did. And it looks much worse for shapes with alpha — they overlap with darker antialiased lines.

Comment: But maybe I sholud try separately render color and alpha with antialiasing off and later stitch them together. Will try.